# Spectrum of Laplace-Beltrami operator on tensors

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M, g)$ be a complete Riemannian manifold diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$. Under appropriate geometric assumptions concerning the geometry near infinity, but *without* any curvature sign assumptions, is the spectrum of the Laplace-Beltrami operator known to be qualitatively similar to other situations? (i.e. positive, discrete, ... )

Comment: Discrete? That's not true even in the scalar case.

Comment: But for the Laplace-Beltrami operator, if $T$ is a smooth, compactly supported tensor field, and denoting by $\langle,\rangle$ the metric pairing of tensors, then $\int_M \langle\triangle g T,T\rangle = - \int_M \langle \nabla T, \nabla T\rangle$ which should give you whatever positivity (or negativity I guess) you want.